# How to display employeephoto from database on listbox item click

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a listbox that retrieves employeedata, and when I click on employee, I get his firstname, lastname and his photo.

I did everything until displaying the image from database. I have this code below. When I click on employeename in listbox, I want to load and display his photo alongside with his name too.
(SQL column EmployeePhoto is "image" type, where I successfully inserted employee images as binary.

Crawled this subject in stack but did not find a useful solution that I could understand. Need your kind help, thanks.

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //select listbox item
        {

          try
          {
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeFirstName,EmployeeLastName,EmployeePhoto FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @myvalue", cnn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myvalue", (ListBox1.SelectedValue));
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
                    TextBox2.Text = dr.GetString(1);

                    //want to display EmployeePhoto in ID:Image1 that was saved as binary

                }
            }
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you fixed about listbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would save the image to the file System (using `File.WriteAllBytes()`). And then show the file from the file system in the image box.

Comment: thanks I think saving the photo into folder is better for me now.

Answer (score 0):

You need image handler (ASHX) in order to display binary data to browser.

[Image Handling In ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126421/Image-Handling-In-ASP-NET)

For example,

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{     
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Query image data from database based on query string value.
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(YourImageByte);
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get { return false; }
    }

}

// Usage
Image1.ImageUrl ="ImageHandler.ashx?id=5"
```

Comment: this is too complicated because I don't know how to bind it into my listbox selection

Comment: ***Why downvote?*** OP said images are stored in Database, so ImageHandler is the proper way to display binary image from database.

Comment: I didn't downvote :) I don't even have enough reputation to downvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ListView` control and not  `ListBox`.

ListViewiItem has an `ImageIndex` property,that enables you to specify the index of the image to render from the it (It supports binding as well)